# A general answer to the number of solutions to an inequality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given the following inequality:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + .... + x_N < r$

we are asked to solve the number of non-negative integer solutions

could the solution be described as:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \dfrac{(k+n-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}$

I think this would give all the cases less than $r$ and how many ways there are to solve them, and then summing them would give the total answer. A combinatorics book I read did it another way that I didn't like and was wondering if I could use this solution instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is a much faster way to do it. We want the sum to be less than $r$, so less than or equal to $r-1$. Introduce a new variable $x_{N+1}$. The number of solutions is then the number of solutions of the equation $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{N+1}=r-1$ in non-negative integers. You know a formula for that.

**Remark:** Your procedure is correct. However, it is a long sum, and substantially more complicated to evaluate than the expression we obtain by introducing the additional variable $x_{N+1}$.

The idea was simple. I have say $99$ candies, and want to distribute perhaps all, perhaps none, perhaps something in between, to  say $12$ kids. Imagine a $13$-th kid, who will get any leftovers. There are just as many ways to distribute *all* the candies to the $13$ kids as there are ways to distribute $0$ or more  of the $99$ candies to the $12$ kids.